# "Groupby" to multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I'm pulling data from SQL, and get it in the following format:
[image]

I'm trying to use the "Groupby" function, to create unique Pandas Dataframes for each Identifier like in the picture. I have a list of all the identifiers (which in reality are different than (1,2,3 etc). How do I go about this?

I eventually want to Export it all to Excel (as is required by my job). Therefore, I would like to keep it all within one loop, so something like:

```
sht = xw.Book()  
for i in (0, "Number of Unique Identifier"):  
     Dataframe_i = Hist_Prices.groupby('Element i of the Unique identifier list')
     sht.sheets.add("DF_i")  
     sht.sheets['DF_i'].range('A1').value = Dataframe_i
     i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
identifiers = sorted(df['identifier'].unique())

for i in identifiers:
    df_i = df[df['identifier'] == i]
    # export df_i to excel sheet
```

Comment: Hi Dan!
Idea works well, but the dataframes writes over itself every loop. Therefore, I end up with 1 dataframe at the end. Would there be a way to have Python understand to iterate every loop? 
/Patrick

Comment: @Natarajan the idea is that you write a DataFrame to excel every iteration (so you would use your code inside the loop). I'm not familiar with `xlwings` but perhaps you could do this: `sht.sheets.add("DF_{}".format(i))`

Comment: you're wrong, this is extremely slow compared to groupby

Comment: @ansev i'm not sure how/why to use groupby here, there is no function to apply

Comment: `for i, group in df.groupby('identifier'):`.... `group` give you the dataframe that you want save